# Using grep/cat as a dictionary in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix

I need to make it so the words in my text file are checked for if they appear in a dictionary text file. I need it to output the words that do not appear in the text file.

I currently have:
cat text.txt | grep -vi english.txt

text is the text file of words that need to be checked and english.txt is my dictionary.
Currently, I just get back all of the words that are in my text.txt file (where I am purposely putting words that should not go through, meaning they are in the dictionary), what am I doing wrong?

(This is for hw so I have to use cat/grep)

Answer (score 1):

try this line:

```
grep -viFf english.txt text.txt
```

If this didn't work for your file, you need give some example lines of your text.txt and english.txt.

Comment: I tried that, it just gives me nothing back. well currently I just have random words in text.txt so stuff like
pineapple
cherry
lfkjadflksj
blah

english.txt is written as a list of words:
A
Aani
Aaron
and so on

Comment: @boop, we have to know how the words were saved in your files. one word per line? or with some delimiters... grep is line based processing tool, I assume you have known about that, so I gave that answer.

Comment: ah english.txt has one word per line. I need it to work with text.txt even if it has many words in one line. I know I need to use grep... so I thought it was okay since english.txt has each word on a separate line. @kent

Comment: `grep -viwFf english.txt text.txt` would be safer. if you have each work per line. but since you told the cmd without `-w` returned nothing, this line won't help either.  btw, "gives nothing back" means you got empty output after the cmd executed, or it took long time, you pressed ctrl-c? @boop

Comment: It quickly executed and gave empty output. @Kent

Comment: @boop Show your text files.

Comment: I just figured this out actually. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @boop, so any answers you should share to us? We can also vote on your own reply.